# How to format the date in the data source in Access form?

Tags: ms-access, datasource

I get errors trying to format and handle the date in the data source of a textbox.

I am trying to calculate a sum of fields in the last month

```
=DSum("Betrag"; "tbl_Ausgaben";
    "[Datum] > #" 
    & DateAdd ('m'; -1; Date()) - Day (DateAdd ('m'; -1; Date()))     //should returns e.g. 31-05-2023
    & "# AND [Datum] <= #" 
    & Date() - Day(Date())                                            //should returns e.g. 30-06-2023
    & "#")
```

But I get error as resault.
I tried to make the code as simple as possible to find out the issue like:

```
=DSum("Betrag"; "tbl_Ausgaben"; "[Datum] > DateAdd ('m'; -1; Date())")
**OR**
=DomSumme("Betrag";"tbl_AusgabenPersonal";"[Datum] > #" & Date() & "#")
```

But that also returns an error.
I think it is because the date format in Germany is dd.mm.yyyy and Access needs dd-mm-yyyy
So I tried to format it with:

```
=Format(Date();"dd-mm-yyyy")
```

But Access changes it after pressing ok to

```
=Format(Datum();"""dd-""mm""-yyyy""")
```

and the resault is: dd-07-yyyy instead of 02-07-2023

Why does the format function get so strange?

Comment: p.s. Datum = Date on German

Comment: In SQL you need the American date notation "#"&month(date())&"/"&day(date())&"/"&year(date())&"#"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't concatenate the criteria, use direct calculation with `DateSerial`:

```
=DSum("Betrag"; "tbl_Ausgaben";
"[Datum] >= DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) - 1, 1) And [Datum] < DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1)")
```

Comment: What would happen in this case if we have January? Wouldn't that generat a wrong date of 2023/00/dd?

Comment: Perfect, it works. thank you. And your hint showed me also my mistake: German Access uses semicolons in function of data sources like DateAdd ('m'; -1; Date()). But by using them in a criteria, I should use the american fomat with commas. That means DateAdd ('m', -1,Date()) or as you wrote with DateSerial(y,m,d)

Answer (score 0):

The Format function converts to the German locale.
Use a function to convert it to a SQL date:

```
Public Function SQL_date(datum As Date) As String
    SQL_date = "#" & Month(datum) & "/" & Day(datum) & "/" & Year(datum) & "#"
End Function
```

Comment: I am trying to solve it only with the data source property without VBA.